# Why rust collect method works different on two almost identical functions

Tags: rust

I was doing rustlings to learn rust and I just finished iterators3, but I don't understand why funtions:

```
// Output: Ok([1, 11, 1426, 3])
fn result_with_list() -> Result<Vec<i32>, DivisionError> {
    let numbers = vec![27, 297, 38502, 81];
    let division_results = numbers.into_iter().map(|n| divide(n, 27));
    let x: Result<Vec<i32>, DivisionError> = division_results.collect();
    println!("{x:?}");
    x
}
```

and

```
// Output: [Ok(1), Ok(11), Ok(1426), Ok(3)]
fn list_of_results() -> Vec<Result<i32, DivisionError>> {
    let numbers = vec![27, 297, 38502, 81];
    let division_results = numbers.into_iter().map(|n| divide(n, 27));
    let x:Vec<Result<i32, DivisionError>> = division_results.collect();
    println!("{x:?}");
    x
}
```

I don't understand why they returns other values despite the fact that they are very similar

(P.S. that's how function divide looks like: `pub fn divide(a: i32, b: i32) -> Result<i32, DivisionError>`)

[rustling iterators3 exercise](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/main/exercises/standard_library_types/iterators3.rs)

Comment: They don't return "other values". They return them as different data structures, just as requested.

Comment: By the way, "almost identical" means "different", so why are you surprised ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand why they returns other values despite the fact that they are almost identical

Because the part which is different is very relevant: one uses [the implementation of `FromIterator` for `Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#impl-FromIterator%3CResult%3CA%2C%20E%3E%3E-for-Result%3CV%2C%20E%3E):

> Takes each element in the Iterator: if it is an Err, no further elements are taken, and the Err is returned. Should no Err occur, a container with the values of each Result is returned.

while the other uses [the implementation of `FromIterator` for `Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-FromIterator%3CT%3E-for-Vec%3CT%2C%20Global%3E), which just creates a vector from the iterator.

So the first version accumulates successful results, and returns the first failure if there is one, while the second version just collects all the results regardless of their success or failure.

Comment: I want to shout out to whomever authored that documentation you linked for `Result`.  It's clear with 3 examples showing effectively all possible use cases, along with clear proof on how it works (stopping early).  And no, this is not a self shout-out.  It's far above standard for the industry.  Rust's doc is generally OK, this is better than just OK.